# How to get cursor from mqlread() when using Freebase API?

Tags: python, json, freebase, mql

I'm using the Python-Freebase module's [mqlread()](http://www.google.com/codesearch/p?hl=en#DXpVckidmh4/trunk/freebase/api/session.py&q=mqlread%28%29%20package%3ahttp://freebase-python%5C.googlecode%5C.com&l=607).  Using the following query:

```
query = [{
  "cursor": True,
  "id":     None,
  "type":   "/games/game",
  "mid":    None,
}]
```

That returns 100 entries, but the result does not include "cursor".  If you run the query manually you get something like:

```
{ "code": "/api/status/ok", "cursor": "eNqFj8FqwzAQRD-mF4sisrtaaaWlhP6H8MHYNTUEW8hpKP36KjgU2kvnMoeZ4THjR923qhKS07wpAvR5VZbYBIL9sE76FDGAs-yCA_FISprL_nWUt5tC383L59ukh9llH_TvpL7Y7rYUdZ4CN9iRITB6vTwnAhriCAwAgXGO8Etkz48dicnvy3ptTGO6OwgsBwIfwJNeHpDWowgh_URO63-M0Z7vM0neGZNL3RrihBKFU_uZS2l3sT-9cpIBaRrnOE8JhaAhQL4B9ZFRmg==", "result": [

{
  "id":   "/en/cities_and_knights_of_catan",
  "mid":  "/m/02hq3",
  "type": "/games/game"
},
....
```

Which contains the "cursor".  But the result from:

```
freebase.mqlread(query, extended=True)
```

Will return:

```
[{u'type': u'/games/game', u'id': u'/en/cities_and_knights_of_catan'}, ...
```

Which strips out "code" and "cursor".  How can I get the "cursor"?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I found that the Freebase-Python module actually includes a method that takes care of cursoring for you.  Just call mqlreaditer(query, extended=true), and that will return a Python generator that you can iterate through.  Behind the scenes the Freebase module will query and keep track of the cursor, return results on demand until a "false" cursor is reached.

Very simple!

Answer (score 0):

Support for MQL envelope parameters was dropped, presumably accidentally, in the 1.0.8 release of the Freebase Python library.

If not don't need MQL extensions, you can just drop the parameter `extended=True` parameter and use `mqlreaditer(query)`.

If you need MQL extensions (or other envelope parameters), you'll have to fall back to 1.0.6 until someone fixes the problem and does a new release.

```
 sudo easy_install freebase==1.0.6
```